# aibo Web API をpythonを使って実行するとエラー: SyntaxError: invalid syntax

Tags: python, aibo-developer

SONYが提供しているサンプルコードをGoogle Colaboratoryを使ってやっています。
最後の文に`$ python execute_action_api.py find_object "{\"TargetType\":\"pinkball\"}"`を使って実行したところ、

```
File "<ipython-input-21-cd227b9f8d7e>", line 54 $ python execute_action_api.py find_object "{\"TargetType\":\"pinkball\"}" ^ SyntaxError: invalid syntax
```

というエラーが出ます。どこを直したらできますでしょうか？

ちなみにアクセストークンとdeviceIdの取得のところ以外は変えておらず、そのまま貼り付けています。

サンプルコード：
https://developer.aibo.com/jp/docs#%E3%82%B5%E3%83%B3%E3%83%97%E3%83%AB%E3%82%B3%E3%83%BC%E3%83%89

Answer (score 1):

※ line 54 で `SyntaxError: invalid syntax` と表示されたので、54行を見るべきなのでしょうが...

Google Colab は、クラウド上の Jupyter notebookですよね。
件のサンプルプロクラムを、Code セルに打ち込んで、さらに

```
python execute_action_api.py find_object "{\"TargetType\":\"pinkball\"}"
```

を追加して実行してみたということですね。
そのコードセルを実行しても、`find_object` は実行されないはずです。
sys.argv[1] は `find_object` ではないからです。

`if __name__ ==`  以下をコメントアウト（または削除）して `do_action` 関数に適当な引数を付けて直接呼んでみてはいかがでしょうか？

```
"""
if __name__ == '__main__':
    length = len(sys.argv)
    if length == 3:
        do_action(sys.argv[1], sys.argv[2])
    else :
        print("execute_action_api.py <action api name> <parameters>")
        exit(1)
"""

do_action( "find_object", "{\"TargetType\":\"pinkball\"}")
```

こちらで試したところ Time out になりました。 少なくとも syntax error は出ません。

Answer (score 1):

自分も試してみました。
他の方が書かれているとおり、Google Colaboratory 上では不要な下記を削除し、

```
if __name__ == '__main__':
    length = len(sys.argv)
    if length == 3:
        do_action(sys.argv[1], sys.argv[2])
    else :
        print("execute_action_api.py <action api name> <parameters>")
        exit(1)
```

上記を削除した位置に、かわりに

```
do_action("play_motion",  "{\"Category\":\"bark\", \"Mode\":\"NONE\"}")
```

などを追加して実行すると、aiboが反応してくれると思います。(これは1回わんと鳴くモーションの実行です)

エラーが出るときは、下記の箇所に、参考リンクをみて取得した正しい文字列を入れてください。

```
headers = {
'Authorization': 'Bearer ここにトークン文字列(かなり長い)を入れる',
}

BASE_PATH = 'https://public.api.aibo.com/v1'
DEVICE_ID = "ここにデバイスIDを入れる"
```

参考 [https://developer.aibo.com/jp/docs#アクセストークンの取得](https://developer.aibo.com/jp/docs#%E3%82%A2%E3%82%AF%E3%82%BB%E3%82%B9%E3%83%88%E3%83%BC%E3%82%AF%E3%83%B3%E3%81%AE%E5%8F%96%E5%BE%97)

タイムアウトが発生するときは、TIME_OUT_LIMIT = 10 を100など大きな値にしてみると回避できました。